# Adding an image over another image - OpenTK

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, opentk

I can combine two images using below code. But is there any way to place the second image on bottom left of first image?

```
vec4 colorFirstImg = texture2D (sTexture_1, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y));
vec4 colorSecondImg= texture2D (sTexture_2,  vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y));
vec4 result = mix(colorFirstImg , colorSecondImg, colorSecondImg.a);
gl_FragColor =result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course, you just have to scale the texture coordinates. If any component of the texture coordinates is > 1.0, skip the 2nd image, by passing 0.0 to the 3rd argument of [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml):

```c
vec4 colorFirstImg = texture2D(sTexture_1, vTexCoord.xy);

vec2 uv2 = vTexCoord.xy * 2.0;
vec4 colorSecondImg = texture2D(sTexture_2, uv2);

float a = (uv2.x <= 1.0 && uv2.y <= 1.0) ? colorSecondImg.a : 0.0;
vec4 result = mix(colorFirstImg , colorSecondImg, a);

gl_FragColor = result;
```

Comment: size of  first image is 325*277, and the second image is 25*25. But it seems like the second image loses it's aspect ratio on the output and show as very big in size. Actually I need a small icon on bottom left of first image.

Comment: @user2431727 `vec2 uv2 = vTexCoord.xy * vec2(325.0/25.0, 277.0/25.0);`